# Virtualbox 5.2.8 freezes Ubuntu 16.04.4 with kernel version 4.13.16

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, freeze

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04.4 with kernel version 4.13.16.
I have installed the latest version of Virtualbox (5.2.8).
The guest I have is from an older version of Virtualbox (I don't remember the version) and it contains Windows 10.

Every time I run the guest Windows 10, it freezes the host system. The freeze always happens during the login to the Windows 10. It used to work normally on the old installation of Virtualbox.

The other similar problems I've found on the internet solve the issue by updating Virtualbox to v5.2. But since i already have the 5.2 version, I don't know how to fix the issue.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue is specific related to the Version... 
Usually Virtualbox issues are related to drivers and accelerated graphics support.
Are you using the latest Drivers ?

Comment: I'm using nouveau display.  I fixed the problem by reinstalling Windows 10 on a new image. Maybe the next person with the same problem might find this helpful.